# Firebase: Writing Custom Callable Cloud Function vs Cloud Firestore Trigger Function

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I learned all about Google Cloud Functions Triggers and I understood that they are good for doing some data preprocessing before write/update/delete happens in Cloud Firestore. This is true right?

However, instead of listening to changes in the database, I would like to write custom code in Cloud Functions and call it directly from the client SDK.

The reason I want to do this is because I don't want to have long complicated database integration logic in my client code. I just want to call a cloud function named `createGame` for instance and let the custom cloud function handle the nested calls to the Firestore, do sanity checks and return me with only the clean data that the client will be displaying.

I found out that there is a Flutter plugin for this called [cloud_functions](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/cloud_functions).
Also this documentation shows how to write [custom callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

We can write the custom callable Cloud Function as follows:

```
exports.createGame = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
  return {
     ...
  }
});
```

We can call the corresponding custom callable Cloud Function from Flutter client as follows:

```
final dynamic response = await CloudFunctions.instance.call(
                        functionName: 'createGame',
                        parameters: <String, dynamic>{
                          'message': 'hello world!',
                          'count': clientCount,
                        },
                      );
```

There are tons of Cloud Functions trigger examples/videos/tutorials. But very few of callable Cloud Functions. That's why I am a little skeptic about this subject.

**Question:**
My question is if this is good practice? Or should I do what this specific Cloud Function is doing from the client? Please answer while keeping *pricing*, *speed*, *reliability* and other factors in mind also:)

One last thing,
The function implementation uses `https.onCall`. Do you think `https` is slowing things down?

Comment: HTTPS is used anyway. Not using HTTPS is bad practice in general. I don't see a disadvantage of using cloud functions over "trigger" functions.

Comment: In your case, it's fine to use a callable function but I see you are waiting for the response from the function in the client... what happens if the client has a network issue? You might never hear about this response.

Comment: @Firebaser Is there a way to catch this kind of errors in the client?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the feedback. Is this too bad for pricing perspective?

Comment: "Is this too bad for pricing perspective" I haven't found anything in  https://firebase.google.com/pricing that would indicate it could cost more.